# If X is any subset of $\mathbb{R}$, bounded and not closet what happened with continuity of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

So the function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ define by $f=\dfrac{1}{x-a}$ with $a \in \bar{X}/X$ is continuos becouse is the composition of 2 continuous functions, for other hand i need to proof $f$ not is uniformly continuous but i have some problems here i try this

If $f$ uniformly continuous preserve the Cauchy sequence, so $a \in \bar{X}/X$ in this case exist a a sequence $(x_n)_n\subset X$such that $x_n \to a$, then X is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is complete for this reason $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence so I need to proof this $(f(x_n))_n$ is not a Cauchy sequence so $\lim f(x_n)= \dfrac{1}{x_n-a}=\infty$ for this reason $(f(x_n))_n$ is divergent and not is a Cauchy sequence.

in conclusion, $f$ is continuous but not is uniformly continuous, I did well?

Comment: I would not have done it like that, but it is correct indeed.

Answer (score 1):

$f: X \to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x)={\dfrac{1}{x-a} } $  with  $a \in \bar{X}/X$

$f$ is not uniformly continuous because it is not possible to assign a finite value at $a$ as $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) $ doesn't exists finitely.

Reason : Suppose, $f:X\to \Bbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous and since
$\Bbb{R}$ is complete $f$ has a unique uniform extension $\hat{f}:\overline {X} \to \Bbb{R}$.